# Flash messages not picking up bootstrap styling

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, frontend, flash-message

First off thanks for the help.

I created a small flask web app to track items "to-do". As part of the app, I have added a number of flash messages to assist with the login, registrations, etc. I seem to have the information feeding to the browswer correctly, but the styling from the bootstrap classes are not show just plain text messages.

Here is the base html of the flask app.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='ToDoList.css')}}" />
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="site-header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
              <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Just Do It Already</a>
                  <div class="navbar-nav ">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('profile') }}">Profile</a>
                     {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                           <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
                           <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('new_post') }}">New Task</a>
                     {% else %}
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('log_in') }}">Login</a> 
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>          
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </nav>
          </header>
          <main role="main" class="container">
            <div class='row'>
              <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
                  {% if messages %}
                    {% for category, message in messages %}
                      <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                        {{ message }}
                      </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
      </div>
      </div>
      </main>
      
    
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My flask messages all contain categories that show in the chrome dev tools inspection, just the message is not styled.

Any idea what i missed here?
[image: output in chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `alert-error` class in bootstrap, you need to use `alert-danger` or `alert-warning`. you can see all the options [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/)

```
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  A simple primary alert—check it out!
</div>
<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
  A simple secondary alert—check it out!
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  A simple success alert—check it out!
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  A simple danger alert—check it out!
</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
  A simple warning alert—check it out!
</div>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  A simple info alert—check it out!
</div>
<div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
  A simple light alert—check it out!
</div>
<div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
  A simple dark alert—check it out!
</div>
```

So your category should be `danger` or `warning`, for example:

```
flash('Login failed etc etc', 'danger')
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked not sure why i thought error was an acceptable class.

Comment: I can see how easily one would assume there is an error class through all the alerts options :)